# warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a case

Tags: c, pointers, warnings

I need help please I don't know how to solve this problem of the assignment makes pointer in C

warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a case [enabled by default]
 `openDir = getDirSuperBlock();`
( the arrow is at the equal sign )

```
char* = openDir;
openDir = malloc(128);
openDir = getDirSuperBlock();
```

The `getDirSuperBlock` function is this

```
char* getDirSuperBlock()
{
    char* dir;
    dir = malloc(128);
    int i;
    get_block(4,dir);
    return dir;
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as `C++` when this will not compile under C++: `openDir = malloc(128);`?

Comment: Answers go in the `Answer` section.  Comments go in the comments section.  The code is not C++, so that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you try to call getDirSuperBlock() before you define it, and you don't have a prototype.
When you do this, the C compiler defines it "implicitly" (which means it basically guesses what type it returns and what type/number its arguments should be)
When this happens, it always guesses that your return type is an int. So you define your function as `char* getDirSuperBlock()`, but before you get to that part, your compiler will think it looks like this: `int getDirSuperBlock()`. So you can fix this by moving its declaration above the invocation, or by adding a prototype before calling it, like this:
`char * getDirSuperBlock();` or, you could explicitly cast that `int` to a `char *`, like this: `openDir = (char*)getDirSuperBlock();` but that is probably not a great idea because this implies that int and char* are the same size, which is not the case on every case.